# Expanding Environment variable in string using python

Tags: python, posix

I have a string containing an environment variable, e.g.

```
my_path = '$HOME/dir/dir2'
```

I want parse the string, looking up the variable and replacing it in the string:

```
print "HOME =",os.environ['HOME']
my_expanded_path = parse_string(my_path)
print "PATH =", my_expanded_path
```

So I should see the output:

```
HOME = /home/user1

PATH = /home/user1/dir/dir2
```

Is there an elegant way to do that in Python?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use :  [os.path.expandvars](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.expandvars)

Comment: strange that it's in `os.path`, considering environment variables are used for more than file-system path elements.  I guess I could use `os.path.expandvars('%username%')` instead of `getpass.getuser()`.

Comment: Note that `os.path.expandvars` will not expand and leave intact expressions using variables that are not set.

Comment: It's in `os.path` because it's main purpose is to expand environment variables that point to directories. For all other purposes you should use `os.environ` instead.

Answer (score 14):

```
import string, os
my_path = '$HOME/dir/dir2'
print string.Template(my_path).substitute(os.environ)
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use a [`Template`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#template-strings):

```
from string import Template
import os

t = Template("$HOME/dir/dir2")
result = t.substitute(os.environ)
```